# Trying to have images only below viewport fade in on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transforms

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.superhi.com/blog/how-to-add-web-design-elements-that-fade-in-and-out-on-scroll) for my portfolio website.

I've almost got it working but instead of only fading in images as they come into the window, it is fading the images that are already in the window.

```js
$(document).on("scroll", function () {
  var pageTop = $(document).scrollTop()
  var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height()
  var tags = $("section")

  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    var tag = tags[i]
    if ($(tag).position().top < pageBottom) {
      $(tag).addClass("visible")
    } else {
      $(tag).removeClass("visible")
    }
  }
})
```

```css
section {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 20px);
  transition: all 1.5s;
}

section.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because everything is hidden until the first scroll event fires. To fix this you can manually trigger a scroll event when the page first loads in order to display the `section` elements which are already visible in the viewport.

```
$(document).on("scroll", function () {
  // your code here...
}).trigger('scroll');
```

It's also worth noting that the `scroll` event handler fires for *every pixel* that you scroll by. As such performance is important there so it would be worth optimising that handler function.

```
var $tags = $("section");
var winHeight = $(window).height();

$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  var pageTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  var pageBottom = pageTop + winHeight;
  $tags.each(function() {
    this.classList.toggle(this.offsetTop < pageBottom)
  });
}).trigger('scroll');

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  winHeight = $(this).height();
});
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to namespace this event and turn it off at some point to avoid additional listening when the conditions have been met.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am VERY new to javascript. I don't understand everything you're saying about "optimising the handler function"--Is the code I am using going to slow down my website a lot? I tried using that updated code and it's not working. Is there anything else I need to change in html or css for that to work?

Comment: @CarlEdwards Again, very new to javascript. Is this also concerning loading speed/performance? I have no idea how to namespace or turn the event off.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah it would to an extent. Just imagine, whenever the user is scrolling, your event listener is constantly firing. To namespace, `on()` would come in handy here. You would setup a conditional that would check when the images are all in and then use `off()` to remove the event listener. More info on namespacing here: https://api.jquery.com/on/